# Move position of smooth-scrolling jquery arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am using the jQuery Smooth Scrolling plugin on my site and would simply like to move the arrows which are displayed next to the container of the scrolling elements, rather them being inside it. If you hover over the carousel mid way through the page it will let you scroll left and right. I intend to have the arrows permanently viewable to the left and right. How can I move the arrows outside of the scroller container and show them on the left and right?

Here is a live url link - http://bit.ly/1dIDzFJ
The plugins homepage - http://smoothdivscroll.com/

The arrows are dynamically created/displayed with the jQuery. But here is some of the HTML/CSS for the smooth-scrolling jQuery as implemented right now.

HTML

```
<div class="box-product" id="makeMeScrollable">
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel-product">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <img src="img/ted.jpg" />
                                <p class="product-carousel-title">Angry Birds Adult Costume</p>
                                <h5>ONLY &#163;46.99</h5>
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/addtocart.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end makemescrollable -->
```

CSS

```
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft {
left: 5%;
}

#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
       block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
       accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: You may want to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS to target the arrows:

```
.scrollingHotSpotRight { posistion:relative; right:-50px; }
.scrollingHotSpotLeft { posistion:relative; left:-50px; }
```